# How to select data according to if else condtion in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables and i am getting incorrect result after query,Here is my table

Here is table "notifications"

```
id      userId          shopId          notificationFor         cretedOn
1       NULL            3               vendor                  2020-07-23 09:01:12         
2       152             3               vendor                  2020-07-22 19:03:40
3       NULL            3               vendor                  2020-07-22 09:20:56
```

Here is my table "users"

```
id      first_name          last_name       createdOn
152     abc                 xyz             2020-06-11 14:53:27
```

Here is my table "shop"

```
id      first_name      last_name
3       hdh             jyt
```

Now i want

1. All notification record where shopId='3'
2. AND i want in "notification" table if userId is NULL then fetch first_name and last_name from
   "shop" table otherwise fetch "first_name" and "last_name" from "users" table

How can i do this ?

Comment: Did you try anything like `COALESCE(value1,value2,...);`  or  `CASE ... WHEN` in MySQL?

Comment: @sheetal Added an answer with CASE WHEN.

Comment: By the way, keep a consistent style in naming all your tables and columns. Either snake case or camel case. Don't mix them.

Answer (score 0):

Unions can be bad for performance, but necessary at times.  This is a potential solution:

```
select s.first_name, s.last_name
from notifications n join shop s on (n.shopId = s.id)
where userId is null
UNION
select u.first_name, u.last_name
from notifications n join users u on (n.userId = u.id)
where userId is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT notifications.id, notifications.notificationFor, (
CASE 
WHEN notifications.userId IS NULL 
THEN CONCAT(shop.firstName, shop.lastName) 
ELSE CONCAT(users.firstName, users.lastName) 
END 
)
as customerName
FROM `notifications` JOIN shop ON shop.id = notifications.shopId
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = notifications.userId
WHERE notifications.shopId=3
```

> Note the `LEFT JOIN` is used on `users` table.